What is the fastest way to drop consecutive duplicates a List[int] column?
I have a Polars DataFrame which has a column containing a variable length list of numbers in each row. For each row I need to drop consecutive duplicates from the list.
So for example:
[5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7] => [5, 4, 5, 6, 7]  
[3, 4, 4, 5, 6] => [3, 4, 5, 6]  
[2, 2] => [2]  
[1] => [1]  

What is the fastest and most performant way to do this in Polars?

I imagine the downvotes are due to the fact that your example only requires a few more additions to make it runnable code. Perhaps you can fix that.

You can use Polars.Expression.rle for contiguous runs of values. Since the values are in a list you would do this within a  list.eval.
Using the data from @Roman Pekar…
import polars as pl
from polars import col
pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=10)

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "data": [
        [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
        [3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
        [2, 2],
        [1]
]})

print(
    df.with_columns(
        col('data').list.eval(pl.element().rle().struct.field('values'))
        .alias('contiguous')
    )
)
# shape: (4, 2)
# ┌────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
# │ data                           ┆ contiguous      │
# │ ---                            ┆ ---             │
# │ list[i64]                      ┆ list[i64]       │
# ╞════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
# │ [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7] ┆ [5, 4, 5, 6, 7] │
# │ [3, 4, 4, 5, 6]                ┆ [3, 4, 5, 6]    │
# │ [2, 2]                         ┆ [2]             │
# │ [1]                            ┆ [1]             │
# └────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘


that's a nice one

As at the moment there's no filter() method for list (see similar question/answer here), you can either use Expr.list.eval() for this:
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "data": [
        [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
        [3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
        [2, 2],
        [1]
]})

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("data").list.eval(
        pl.element().filter(
            pl.element().ne_missing(pl.element().shift())
       )
    )
)

┌─────────────────┐
│ data            │
│ ---             │
│ list[i64]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ [5, 4, 5, 6, 7] │
│ [3, 4, 5, 6]    │
│ [2]             │
│ [1]             │
└─────────────────┘

So the idea is to compare your list with shifted list, which we can get by using Expr.shift().
[5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]      <- original 
   [5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7]   <- shifted

keep only ones which are not equal to shifted

 5  _  _  4  _  5  _  6  _  7       <- _ if removed


Thanks. One problem with the shift method is that I lose either the first or the last element and have to add it back manually. I'll try the ne_missing method because I do have the exploded data initially anyway and create the list column for it myself. So a bit like an XY-problem, actually.
